# Using jQuery to display hidden row closest() to selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to jQuery, but I'm trying to display the closest hidden table row when a user selects the (visable) one above it.

HTML

```
 Click on a row for more info:
<table>
    <tr><td><p>Name</p></td><td><p>Age</p></td><td><p>Info</p></td></tr>
    <tr class="child"><td><p>Blah blah blah.</p>
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td><p>Name</p></td><td><p>Age</p></td><td><p>Info</p></td></tr>
    <tr class="child"><td><p>Blah blah blah.</p>
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td><p>Name</p></td><td><p>Age</p></td><td><p>Info</p></td></tr>
    <tr class="child"><td><p>Blah blah blah.</p>
    </td></tr>    
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $("tr.child").hide();

    $("table").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();

        var $target = $(event.target);
        $target.closest("tr.child").toggle();
    });
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfwYS/1162/). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: closest() is used to find ancestors and not children. Use find()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.closest()` traverses up the DOM structures over the ancestors.

With the given table structure, the next tr should be toggled using [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

You can do something like this

```
$("table tr").click(function(event) {
    $(this).next(".child").toggle();
});
```

Here is a demo **https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/mfwYS/1166/**

Answer (score 1):

What you have is good. You need to first find the closest `<tr>` element using the `closest()` function.

Then using the `nextAll()` function to find all the following `.child` classes after that element but choose only the first returned

```
$("table").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    var $target = $(event.target);
    $target.closest("tr").nextAll('.child').first().toggle();
});
```

See this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/mfwYS/1165/

Comment: in your demo, if a visible `tr.child` is clicked it is toggling the next `tr.child`s  as well. OP mentioned *when the user selects (visible one) above it*